# How to import one single row of data from excel to one list item in a SharePoint 2010 list?

Tags: list, splistitem, excel, import

I have a problem where we want users to attach a file to a new item and the SharePoint list will automatically read on row or column of data (maybe 20 cells-worth of data) and populate some additional fields within the SharePoint list. 
We had a partial solution to this created for us a few months back, but the person has since left the company and now I am struggling to work out how to re-create this. I assum it will take some coding, but I feel that I am in a good position to try and re-create such code from scratch if need be so that this can be achieved.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions,
Elliot.

Answer (score 0):

Plese try to import excel data as a new List. 
Site Actions=>Advanced Setting(where you can create list) =>Import Excel to List (something like that)
Then specify on top of the excel book your coulumns such as title,address, etc and select all table diapason.

After Import you there will be appear new List.You can also copy several items from another List programmatically to just creted List if you wish.